# Compare second row from file 1.csv with complete file 2.txt and output differences

Tags: bash, string-comparison

I have two text files, 1.txt, and 2.txt.

1.txt

```
https://soundcloud.com/track1,artisturi067
https://soundcloud.com/track4,artisturi428
https://soundcloud.com/track72,artisturi023
https://soundcloud.com/track22,artisturi181
```

2.txt

```
artisturi181
artisturi428
artisturi172
artisturi096
```

And I'm looking for a way to compare lines from the 1.txt,2 column with the whole file lines from the 2.txt, resulting in something like this:

3.txt

```
https://soundcloud.com/track1,artisturi067
https://soundcloud.com/track72,artisturi023
```

Python, Bash for Windows, or even Powershell would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you haven't done so please take the [Tour] and read at least the help about [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the [`join` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) installed, you could do this:

```
$ join -t, -12 -21 -v1 -o1.1 -o1.2 <(sort -t, -k2 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
https://soundcloud.com/track72,artisturi023
https://soundcloud.com/track1,artisturi067
```

- `-t,`: sets the record separator to be a comma, since that's what file 1.txt uses
- `-12 -21`: says to join the 2nd field of the 1st file (`-12`) with the 1st field of the 2nd file (`-21`)
- `-v1`: tells `join` to only output those rows in the 1st file that have no match in the 2nd file
- `-o1.1 -o1.2`: says that we want to output the 1st and 2nd fields of the 1st file
- `<(sort -t, -k2 1.txt)`: since `join` requires sorted files as inputs, we use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to sort the file 1.txt based on its 2nd key (`-k2`) and using comma as a delimiter (`-t,`)
- `<(sort 2.txt)`: similarly, we sort the 2nd input file, but since it contains a single column, we don't have to specify either a separator, or a key, as we did for the previous file

Comment: Don't you feel like you just did someones homework now? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf not really, no :) I use questions like these as opportunities for practice.

Comment: Too bad, I strongly believe, with delivering ready to use solutions on request without the need for own effort of the questioner, that way we're growing a generation of lazy but nevertheless demanding kids with no drive or will to do or to figure out something by themselfs. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Olaf We're getting a bit off-topic, so not sure this is the best place to discuss this, but... I partly agree with you, however, questions & answers remain public and available to everyone, so that means a lot of people will blindly copy existing answers (SO is famous for this after all). By your reasoning, I think we'd have to delete an answer once the OP accepts it. So, I prefer to think that the answer might spark curiosity, in the OP or future readers, rather than invest my energy in educating their approach to learning.